# Theano Path in Python Directory - RuntimeError

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, theano

I'm configuring python, theano, keras, tensorFlow.  I nearly had it working, but was receiving a version error when using pygpu0.6.9.  So I updated theano version (per some instructions).  Aftwerwards, I ran the test file again.  I didn't receive the pygpu error anymore, but instead I'm receiving this error:

> "You have the theano directory in your Python Path.  This do [sic] not work in Python 3."

This is probably a simple fix, but I'm relatively new to this.  Thank you for any help.

PS

```
C:\program files\anaconda3> python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from theano import function, config, shared, tensor
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\__init__.py", line 79, in <module>
    "You have the theano directory in your Python path."
RuntimeError: You have the theano directory in your Python path. This do not work in Python 3.
```

Comment: Which version of Python and Theano you use?

Answer (score 0):

You got error on following [code](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/e6acc109e97cd1d05702eafc77d9d9cba8771849/theano/__init__.py#L73)

```
rpath = os.path.realpath(__path__[0])
for p in sys.path:
    if os.path.realpath(p) != rpath:
        continue
    if PY3:
        raise RuntimeError(
            "You have the theano directory in your Python path."
            " This do not work in Python 3.")
    else:
        warnings.warn(
            "You have the theano directory in your Python path."
            " This is will not work in Python 3.")
    break
```

I don't know why, but authors check if path to Theano is in `sys.path` (which initialized from the environment variable PYTHONPATH). Try to remove path to Theano from PYTHONPATH env variable.